# Django admin: how to add Save button to the top of list view

Tags: django, django-admin

When there are list editable fields, a Save button appears at the bottom in Django admin list view. (Surrounded with a red box in the picture).
[image]

How to add the same Save button to the top as well? (The expected result is surrounded with a green box in the picture.)

For object change view Django provides a simple solution, but there seems to be no built-in option for list view.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done with JavaScript.

First we need a JS function, which would find the Save button row from the bottom of the page and insert a copy to the top. In my case it lives in `static/common/js/save-buttons-to-list-view-top.js`.

```
'use strict'
var $ = django.jQuery

$(document).ready(function () {
  var saveButtonRow = $('.paginator')[0]
  var resultsDiv = $('#changelist-form > div.results')[0]

  if (saveButtonRow && resultsDiv) {
    $(saveButtonRow).clone().insertBefore(resultsDiv);
  }
})
```

This script needs to be added to all admin change list views by overriding the `change_list.html` template.

Create a file `templates/admin/change_list.html` with the following content:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/media/common/js/save-buttons-to-list-view-top.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

To make this work, check whether you have configured template options in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments my original answer was wrong. To get it in the list view override the changelist.html of your model with a file that contains the following:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

    {% load admin_list %}

{% block result_list %}
    {% pagination cl %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Just for reference. There is the option ModelAdmin.save_on_top ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_on_top))

Comment: I know, I'm late, but this option doesn't work in the changelist page.

Comment: This is for change form but op wants in the list view